# How to prove that $A$ (a $n\times n$ matrix) is diagonalizable, given that $rank(A) = 1$ and $A^2 != 0$?

Tags: diagonalization

So I have proved that $0$ is an eigenvalue for the above matrix and that the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $n-1$. I know if I can find one more eigenvector for some other eigenvalue, I will be able to prove this. But I don't know how to find this other eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$ then $A=vw^T$ for some non-zero vectors $v,w$.
Then $Av=vw^Tv=\langle w,v\rangle v$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $x$ is in the column space of $A$, then $Ax$ must also be in the column space of $A$.

Comment: I understand this. But how does this makes finding the other vector any easy? How can I use this to get an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "the other vector"? In any case, my point is that the rank of $A$ is $1$. So, the column space is one dimensional. So, if $x$ is a non-zero element of the columns space and $Ax$ is in the column space, then $Ax$ is a multiple of $x$.